# Manually Add conversions in Marketing Cloud/SF

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion

While waiting for conversion tracking to be implemented we sent an email and are using Google Analytics to track conversion. Is there a place where I can manually type in the number?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a support ticket to ask Salesforce to enable additional parameters for links in your email, once it is enabled, you can configured it in email property.